# IE issue: disable linkbutton onclientclick and continue doing the onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Some of my users reported me problems that the ASP.NET application hangs out and won't go on in IE (in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari - it is working!). The thing is that when the user clicks on the button, it should be disabled while the content is loaded, so I disable the button with OnClientClick and then continue with the OnClick function in C# background. But only in IE it isn't working! The button is disabled, but after that nothing happens, the application doesn't continue.

I tried with disabling the button from C#, from jquery, from functions... But it's always the same!

Any ideas?

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="GoButton" runat="server"  Text="<div></div>" CssClass="Go" OnClick="GoButton_Click" OnClientClick="return disablebutton(this);" />


<script>
    function disablebutton(btn) {
        $(btn).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        return true; }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable a LinkButton which has`Enabled="false"`, ASP.NET removes the `href` attribute of the anchor element. In order to allow the postback to occur, you can remove the attribute asynchronously with `setTimeout`:

```
function disablebutton(btn) {
    setTimeout(function () { btn.removeAttribute('href'); }, 10);
    return true; 
}
```

Make sure that the `Enabled` and `OnClick` properties are not modified in code-behind, so that the LinkButton is enabled and works correctly after the postback.

Comment: It´s an application like doing exams. After I click on the button, it should be disabled and the question should be loaded. When I answer the question, the button gets again enabled because of the postback (functions from behind). When I use your suggestion, it works only for the first time, and after that it´s disabled and not working again.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "it works only for the first time". After the postback, is the LinkButton enabled or disabled?

Comment: After the postback it´s enabled again and that´s why it´s working on other browsers, because I disable it but it´s enabled again when it´s time for a new question.
"only for the first time" - I log in, click on the button to get the first question and I get the first! But after that, I cannot click on it anymore because I guess somehow the other click event is not fired or? The button only gets disabled and just staying so.

Comment: I modified my answer with some new code that I tested successfully on various browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE11).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attempting to disable it, you can just remove it's click event.

Try this:

```
function disablebutton(btn) {
    $(btn).bind('click', false);            
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: The same result like I described above :(